# Solving second order nonhomogeneous linear equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So i have the equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + y = \sin(t)$$

I know the first step is to find the corresponding homogeneous equation, which i think would be: $$r^2+1=0$$ giving real roots and therefore the equation is $$y(t)=Ae^{-t}+Be^{t}$$ where A and B are constants. However in my answer book it has $$y(t)=A \sin(t)+B \cos(t)$$ with A and B as constants, could anyone explain where i went wrong?

And then how do i find the particular solution next? Thanks

Comment: the roots of $r^2 + 1 = 0$ are $r = i, -i$ not $1, -1.$

Answer (score 2):

the roots of $r^2 + 1 = 0$ are $r = i, -i$ not $1, -1.$ 
the homogenous solutions of $$x'' + x = \sin t. \tag 1$$  are $\sin t, \cos t.$

the force, the right hand side, is a homogenous solution, this type of forcing equation is called the resonant forcing. you will need to look for a particular solution in the form $$ x = kt\cos t$$ and determine the right value for $k$ by substituting $(1)$ in the equation.

Comment: why is it i and -i? surely $$r^2+1=0$$ can become (r+1)(r-1)=0 with roots r=-1 and r=1?

Comment: @LaurenBathers: No, $(r+1)(r-1)=0$ becomes $r^2-1=0$: Note the minus sign.

Comment: oh yeah obviously! sorry completely missed that! thank you